# windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" Keyboard OverLays Editexts Error

Tags: android, android-edittext, window-soft-input-mode

Tried using  `window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)`
inside the activity.Also tried with **ADJUST_RESIZE** Param It was not working.

**The following code is my manifest for the activity**

```
<activity android:name=".auth.AuthActivity"
          android:theme="@style/NoActionBarTheme"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
</activity>
```

**This is my emulator screenshot**

[image: Emulator screen Shot]
Tried most of the solutions .May be I am missing the right one

Answer (score 0):

you can hide keyboard programmatically when you set error on `editBox`

```
 public void hideKeyboard() {
        View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            if (imm != null) {
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That will not work as I need to show the error as the user inputs the text inside editText

Comment: Yeah i know that but what i need is different. The user needs to be shown the error until it's gone

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ScrollView` in the `layout` and put all your fields in `ScrollView` so they can move vertically. Then when the Keyboard pops out the fields can move easily and nothing will be hidden.

Comment: I am already using a nestedScollView to wrap my constraintLayout

Comment: Are these fields the directly child of the NestedScrollView?

Comment: Can you arrange your layout ina way that NestedScrollView->ConstraintLayout->AllFields

Comment: May be this will work best for scrolling the view better

Comment: Yeah its like this  NestedScrollView->ConstraintLayout->AllFields

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192607/discussion-between-abr-and-abdur-rahman).

Answer (score 0):

Use this it working code

put this code on create

```
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

put manifest this

```
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="player1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="player2"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="player3"/>


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="player4"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```